# The list after performing remove operation is : <filter object at 0x000001D5A0952FA0> error in python

Tags: python, list

```
# Python 3 code to demonstrate
# to remove elements present in other list
# using filter() + lambda

# initializing list
list1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]

# initializing remove list
list2 = [3, 6]

# printing original list
print("The original list is : " + str(list1))

# printing remove list
print("The original list is : " + str(list2))

# using filter() + lambda to perform task
res = filter(lambda i: i not in list1, list2)

# printing result
print("The list after performing remove operation is : " + str(res))

Output-:
The original list is : [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
The original list is : [3, 6]
The list after performing remove operation is : <filter object at 0x000001D5A0952FA0>


Expected output-:
The original list is : [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
The original list is : [3, 6]
The list after performing remove operation is : [1, 4, 7]
```

What is the problem here? Why am I getting that error. I really can't wrap my head around this issue. I found this in website called geeksforgeeks and tried to run it.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-all-values-from-a-list-present-in-other-list/

Comment: That's not an error `filter` returns an object that you can convert to list : `res = list(filter(lambda i: i not in list1, list2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the two lists are in the wrong places and to display the result you can transform the filter object into a list

```
res = list(filter(lambda i: i not in list2, list1))

print("The list after performing remove operation is : " + str(res))

OUTPUTS: The list after performing remove operation is : [1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: I know about lambda with filter...they test that condition in lambda function to the iterablee...what happens here? the condition in lambda function is i not in list2....the iterable is list1,....how does that work...Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @catmum honestly I don't know the inner workings of the filter function, I personally see it as: for each element in list1 check that's not in list 2, given the bool returned by the lamba function filter will yield the elements on wich the condition is true.

Comment: @catmum a more straightforward way to do it is with list comprehensions:
res = [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]

Answer (score 1):

you need to change your filter functions argument. Your code should like this

```
list1 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]

# initializing remove list
list2 = [3, 6]

# printing original list
print("The original list is : " + str(list1))

# printing remove list
print("The original list is : " + str(list2))

# using filter() + lambda to perform task
res = list(filter(lambda i: i not in list2, list1))

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(res)
```

output of this code will be like this

```
The original list is : [1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
The original list is : [3, 6]
[1, 3, 4, 6, 7]
[3, 6]
[1, 4, 7]
```